# What are the files that are cached by default in Symfony

Tags: symfony, caching

The below command clears the Symfony cache.

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

My question is what are the files that Symfony caches out of the box.

UPDATED:
I am aware of the default location var/cache where the files are stored. I am looking for a more precise answer.

Comment: var/cache might give you an idea

Comment: I feel like you're asking B to find out about A (giving the A context might help, what are you trying to achieve?). There essentially is no clear "out of the box", because the "box" is very unspecific and depends on the packages installed, the skeleton used etc. Some very common ones are translations, routes and templates - essentially everything that comes from code inspection, annotations especially, which is relatively expensive, is compiled and cached. Cache invalidation is also different between prod and dev for example ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jakumi. This is what I am looking for " essentially everything that comes..." is there any Symfony guide that I am not aware?

Comment: tbh, it's just from experience. stuff not working and after clearing cache stuff working. The templates is just twig. Annotations/configuration is to some extent connected to https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html , translations ... experience, but it's probably documented somewhere. But I bet you're looking for the compiler passes, it's very powerful and not that easy to get into. I haven't found my way into it yet (no necessity yet either).

Comment: That's a good start. I will further look up by self. Thanks @Jakumi